# How to tell zlib compression in python to NOT use several bytes/characters

Tags: python, zlib, pyserial

In my research I'm developing a tool to send arbitrary data via a radio communication device which is connected via serial.
PySerial is used for the communication

Every command that is sent to the device has the structure is encased in a start/stopbyte, if our payload is e.g. DATA, it looks like

```
cmd = b'\x02' + DATA.encode() + b'\x03'
```

DATA may be large and the communication is very slow, so I'm trying to use zlib for compression.

```
from zlib import compress, decompress
DATA_comp = compress(DATA.encode())
cmd = b'\x02' + DATA_comp + b'\x03'
```

**But** the compression may introduce the characters b'\x02' and b'\x03' somewhere in the payload. This leads to errors since the device firmware treats these as control bytes!

**Is there a way to tell zlib (or any other compression method) to not use several bytes in the compressed output?**

*tl;dr: compression introduces control bytes into a payload that are not treatet by the device*

Comment: Is there truly no way to tell the device to transmit N bytes, rather than "transmit until you see a byte with value X"?   Normally you'd just put the message length near the front.

Comment: Unfortunately the device does not support that, it's a fixed proprietary protocol ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can break the problem into two parts:

1. Compress the data.
2. Transform the compressed data such that it does not contain the byte `3`.

For the second part, you can use many encodings.  For example, [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding does not emit the byte `3`.  Taking that a bit further, you could use base255 encoding with the valid symbols `0-2` and `4-255`.

Comment: If your device uses more "control characters" than just 0x02 and 0x03, remember to choose encoding that leaves out **all** of those. Base64 is certainly a safe choice, but it increases the size of your payload by a constant factor of 4/3, so you might consider Ascii85 instead. In general, see [Binary-to-text encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding)

Comment: @Błotosmętek thats a good point, I noticed that. In the next step I will conduct some performance testing. Ascii85 sounds promising too.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @JohnZwinck I came to the following conclusion (presented in a minimal working example)

```
from zlib import compress, decompress
from base64 import b64encode
DATA_comp = compress(DATA.encode())
DATA_enc = b64encode(DATA_comp)
cmd = b'\x02' + DATA_enc + b'\x03'
```

On the receiving side it's the other way around.

As @Błotosmętek pointed out, the size of the payload is incresed again by a constant factor. Using Ascii85 might be better.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, let zlib do its thing, and then encode the resulting stream of bits to avoid the forbidden bytes. This can be done efficiently and quickly with what amounts to equiprobable Huffman decoding of the stream of bits to the number of symbols less than 256 that are desired. Then encoding that stream of symbols at the other end using the Huffman code, converting it back to the original bit stream.

For a small number of bytes to avoid, you would pull 7 bits from the stream. Depending on the value of the 7 bits, either pull or don't pull one more bit. Map the 7 or 8 bits to the desired subset of bytes. Repeat. Consider zero bits to be appended to the end of the input in order to permit all of the input bits to be used. Reverse to restore, discarding fewer than 8 zero bits produced at the end.

Here is example code:

```
/*
  avoid.c version 1.0, 2 July 2017

  Copyright (C) 2017 Mark Adler

  This software is provided 'as-is', without any express or implied
  warranty.  In no event will the authors be held liable for any damages
  arising from the use of this software.

  Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any purpose,
  including commercial applications, and to alter it and redistribute it
  freely, subject to the following restrictions:

  1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented; you must not
     claim that you wrote the original software. If you use this software
     in a product, an acknowledgment in the product documentation would be
     appreciated but is not required.
  2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and must not be
     misrepresented as being the original software.
  3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source distribution.

  Mark Adler
  madler@alumni.caltech.edu
*/

// Take arbitrary binary input and encode it to avoid specified byte values.
// The number of such values to avoid is the parameter "cut". The input is
// taken as a stream of bits. At each step either 7 or 8 bits of input is coded
// to an output byte. As a result, the input bits are expanded by a factor
// between 1 and about 1.143 (rounded up to the next multiple of 8 bits),
// depending on the value of cut and depending on the input data. cut must be
// in the range 1..128. For random input, the average expansion ratio is
// 1/(1-cut/1024).
//
// avoid() does the encoding, and restore() does the decodng. avoid() uses the
// table map[], which maps the values 0..255-cut to the allowed byte values,
// i.e. the byte values that are not cut. invert_map() is provided to invert
// that transformation to make the table unmap[], which is used by restore().

#include <stddef.h>

// Encode input[0..len-1] into a subset of permitted byte values, which number
// cut less than 256. Therefore cut values are cut from the set of possible
// output byte values. map[0..255-cut] is the set of allowed byte values. cut
// must be in the range 1..128. If cut is out of range, zero is returned and no
// encoding is performed. Otherwise the return value is the size of the encoded
// result. size is the size of the output space in bytes, which should be at
// least the maximum possible encoded size, equal to ceiling(len * 8 / 7). The
// return value may be larger than size, in which case only size bytes are
// written to *out, with the remaining encoded data lost. Otherwise the number
// of bytes written to *out is the returned value.
size_t avoid(unsigned char *output, size_t size,
             unsigned char const *input, size_t len,
             unsigned char const *map, unsigned cut) {
    if (len == 0 || cut < 1 || cut > 128)
        return 0;
    unsigned buf = *input, code = buf;
    int bits = 8;
    size_t in = 1, out = 0;
    for (;;) {
        unsigned less = code >> 1;
        if (less < cut) {
            code = less;
            bits -= 7;
        }
        else {
            code -= cut;
            bits -= 8;
        }
        if (out < size)
            output[out] = map[code];
        out++;
        if (in == len && bits <= 0)
            return out;
        if (in < len) {
            if (bits < 8) {
                buf = (buf << 8) + input[in++];
                bits += 8;
            }
            code = buf >> (bits - 8);
        }
        else
            code = buf << (8 - bits);   // pad with zeros
        code &= 0xff;
    }
}

// Invert the map used by avoid() for use by restore().
void invert_map(unsigned char *unmap, unsigned char const *map, unsigned cut) {
    if (cut < 1 || cut > 128)
        return;
    unsigned k = 0;
    do {
        unmap[k++] = 255;
    } while (k < 256);
    k -= cut;
    do {
        k--;
        unmap[map[k]] = k;
    } while (k);
}

// Restore the data input[0..len-1] that was encoded with avoid(), writing the
// restored bytes to *output. The number of restored bytes is returned. size is
// the size of the output space in bytes, which should be at least the maximum
// possible restored size, equal to len. If the returned value is greater than
// size, then only size bytes are written to *output, with the remainder of the
// restored data lost. unmap[k] gives the corresponding code for character k in
// the range 0..255-cut if k is in the allowed set, or 255 if k is not in the
// allowed set. Characters in the input that are not in the allowed set are
// ignored. cut must be in the range 1..128. If cut is out of range, zero is
// returned and no restoration is conducted.
size_t restore(unsigned char *output, size_t size,
               unsigned char const *input, size_t len,
               unsigned char const *unmap, unsigned cut) {
    if (cut < 1 || cut > 128)
        return 0;
    unsigned buf = 0;
    int bits = 0;
    size_t in = 0, out = 0;
    while (in < len) {
        unsigned code = unmap[input[in++]];
        if (code == 255)
            continue;
        if (code < cut) {
            buf <<= 7;
            bits += 7;
        }
        else {
            buf <<= 8;
            bits += 8;
            buf += cut;
        }
        buf += code;
        if (bits >= 8) {
            if (out < size)
                output[out] = buf >> (bits - 8);
            out++;
            bits -= 8;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```